# How to add Class attribute into Custom Html Helper in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to add `Class` into my Custom Html Helper. I am creating a Html Helper for Image.
I got confused how to add class into custom html helper.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

I want helper method for this scenario.

```
<img src=@model.Path alt="Image" class="img-thumbnail" style="height:20px; width:30px;">
```

Code

```
 public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string alt,string height, string width)
        {
            TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
            tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src));
            tb.Attributes.Add("alt", alt);
            tb.Attributes.Add("height", height);
            tb.Attributes.Add("width", width);

            return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        }
```

Comment: You mean the HTML `class` attribute? What do you get confused about? Just add it ti the params list and then add the vaue to the attributes just as you have done with the other attributes.

Comment: If by class you mean css class, just do this: `tb.Attributes.Add("class", spaceSeparatedClasses);`. Add default classes from within the helper and have another overload which allows the user to pass in attributes. If you look at MVC frameworks, they have simple helpers and then overloads with more parameters. Follow the same pattern.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, I have below code implemented but seems height is not working for me. `@Html.Image(model.Path,"Image","20px","", "img-thumbnail")`

Comment: You are not providing the width. If you do not use the helper and not specify width in your html, does it work? Also keep in mind that `style` is one attribute and you are not passing this to your helper. Right now what your helper is rendering is not the same as your html. In your helper you are not passing style like `style="height:20px; width:30px;"`. You should put that style in a css class and pass the css class name to ur helper instead.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, No this does not work. If I put it inside style attribute then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string alt, string height, string width, params string[] allClasses)
    {
        TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
        tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src));
        tb.Attributes.Add("alt", alt);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(height) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(width))
        {
            StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(height))
                value.AppendFormat("height:{0};", height);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(width))
                value.AppendFormat("width:{0};", width);

            tb.Attributes.Add("style", value.ToString());
        }
        if (allClasses?.Any() ?? false)
            tb.Attributes.Add("class", string.Join(" ", allClasses));

        return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
```

Something like that?

Comment: I tried adding your code then I tried this `@Html.Image(model.Path,"Image","20px","", "img-thumbnail")` where height seems not working. Please suggest me. what is wrong into this.

Comment: @MVC What does the rendered html look like?

Comment: Sorry, i have implemented this code under partial view so could not see rendered html

Comment: This code works fine `<img src=@model.Path alt="Image" class="img-thumbnail" style="height:20px; width:30px;">`

Comment: No. How to add style attribute inside this html helper. please update your answer by adding it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You have this code:

```
<img src=@model.Path alt="Image" class="img-thumbnail" style="height:20px; width:30px;">
```

which works. Now you want to create an html helper so you created this:

```
public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string alt, string height, string width)
{
    TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
    tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src));
    tb.Attributes.Add("alt", alt);
    tb.Attributes.Add("height", height);
    tb.Attributes.Add("width", width);

    return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

but this helper will not produce the exact same html as the one above. It will treat each `height` and `width` as separate attributes and render this:

```
<img src = @model.Path alt="Image" class="img-thumbnail" height="20px" width="30px">
```

**Correct Way**

Whenever you create HTML helpers, see how the MVC Framework has done it because they invest a lot of time and money into making it and thus your code will be more inline with the pattern they use and it will also be more reusable.

It is not a good idea to include any of the properties that are in `style` attribute in your HTML or HTML helper (which just renders HTML eventually). A better approach is to keep the separations of structure and style separate: Separation of Concerns. Here is how to do so the MVC Framework way:

```
public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, object htmlAttributes)
{
    TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
    RouteValueDictionary htmlAttrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    foreach (var thisAttribute in htmlAttrs)
    {
        tb.Attributes.Add(thisAttribute.Key, thisAttribute.Value.ToString());
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

**Usage**

```
@Html.Image(new { Src = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("your path"), Alt = "alt", @Class = "my-stackoverflow-image" })
```

Notice how we are not passing `style` to the helper, that is what you want. You want your HTML to be style free and keep that in CSS file. Finally add your style to the a css file (MVC creates `Site.css` so you can just use that) like this:

```
.my-stackoverflow-image {
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

This is great because if you want to change your style, you do not need to recompile and in some cases when you work in a team, the front end designer (CSS expert) can add all sort of fancy CSS to it. All you need is to tell the front end designer that the image uses `my-stackoverflow-image` class.